# grep summarize lines by strings

Tags: sed, grep

I have a grep'ed string from curl, and I want to summarize lines of by its content.

e. g.
**input**

```
SomethingA v2.3
SomethingA v2.4

SomethingElse v1.1
SomethingElse v1.2
```

**output**

```
SomethingA 2
SomethingElse 1
```

The numbers in the output are not a must, but if easy to achieve, would be very nice. The "v" as the leading space is a fix prefix for the numerics which don't have to contain a dot.

I tried `echo "$str" | grep -Po '(.*(?<=))v[0-9]'`  but it still contains the "v1" .. and I don't know how to reduce the leading strings by multiple matches.

Comment: WIll this solve it? cut -d\  -f1 < input | sort | uniq -c

Comment: Wow didn't know about `uniq` that's amazing! `uniq -u` is exactly what I need, sir!

Comment: There's an excellent chance that you don't need to grep a string from the curl output and then use that string to grep something else which you then cut and count, etc. and instead could just use 1 command to print the final output you want directly from the original curl output. If you'd like help with that then create a question with that curl output and your final output as the [mcve] so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$ awk '{print $1}' filename  | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Note : This will also give a count of the blank lines. If you want to get rid of those, use :

```
$ grep -v '^$'  filename |  awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```